# How to monitoring HTTP requests and responses from/to servlets using Java

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, servlets, executor

I'm testing a Web application written in Java EE using servlets (version 7). I'm sending a lot of HTTP requests to my servlets and I want to know when all requests are completed.

To send requests I'm using an executor. Also I don't know if it is the most efficient way to do this.

```
 for (int i=0; i < numRequests; i++) {
     ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1); 
     Future<util.Response> responseFromServlet = null;
        responseFromServlet = executor.submit(new util.Request(new URL(url)));
     if ( i !=  numRequests -1 ) {
        executor.shutdown();
     } else {
        responseFromServlet.get().getBody(); // suspensive call for last invocation
        executor.shutdown();
     }
  }
```

Actually the executor waits the end of the last invoked HTTP request but it usually is not the last one that completes.

I think that creating a new thread waiting for response of each HTTP servlet is crazy. I can't generate 100-200-300 threads, one for each request!

So is there a way to understand when all servlets end their execution? If needed, I can modify my servlets.

=== Edit ===

To be more precise, here is the Request class implementation:

```
public class Request implements Callable<Response> {
  private URL url;

  public Request(URL url) {
      this.url = url;
  }

  @Override
  public Response call() throws Exception {
      return new Response(url.openStream());
  }
}
```

And this it the Response class:

```
public class Response {
  private InputStream body;

  public Response(InputStream body) {
      this.body = body;
  }

  public InputStream getBody() {
      return body;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an executor is fine, you may want to increase the size of the ThreadPool though to have more concurrent threads performing your requests.

Use a [CoutnDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) initialised with `numRequests` which sits waiting for all the threads to complete.

`util.Request` must call `latch.countDown()` in its `run`method

The code would look like this (handwritten  - not tested)

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n);
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(numRequests); 
for (int i=0; i < numRequests; i++) {

     executor.submit(new util.Request(new URL(url), latch));
}
latch.await(someValue, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

`
**Edit**

Re-implement `util.Request` doing something like

```
 public class Request implements Callable<Response> {
  final private URL url;
  final private CountDownLatch latch;

  public Request(URL url, CountDownLatch latch) {
      this.url = url;
      this.latch = latch;
  }

  @Override
  public Response call() throws Exception {

       try {
          return new Response(url.openStream());
       } 
       catch (Exception e) {

          //do something useful
       }
       finally {
          latch.countDown();
       }
  }
}
```

You may want to consume the stream of you response before you countDown the latch to verify that you get what you expect as a response from your server.

Comment: Thank you! I read CountDownLatch javadoc and it sounds useful! I have some questions: 1) Why should util.Request call the countDown()? Is the request run() method executed after the servlet completes its execution? (I edited my original question with Request and Response classes) 2) If a call executor.submit() a lot of times and I do not invoke executor.shutdown(), the invocation of the first submit() waits a response before proceeding. Maybe should I use execute() instead?

Comment: The Request is a Callable so it is the `call` method that should `countDown` the latch. The latch `await` will stop blocking when the count reaches zero. See my edited answer above

Comment: It worked for me. Tested on Apache Tomcat installed on OS X 10.8, Ubuntu 12.10 and Windows XP. However actually the executor does not create new threads on Windows 7 and we are not able to understand why. We tried to execute it as admin, and change permissions but without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this program to perform a load test, or even otherwise, I'd highly recommend that you use [Jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) instead. Jmeter already does what you are attempting to do and there are many plugins that will allow you to schedule the load / number of thread / time period etc. You can also monitor all HTTP requests through a variety of graphs.

Writing a test for your servlet should [take you less than 5 minutes](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html). The graphs are also easy to generate.

[image: jmeter graph]

If you'd still like to use your custom program to contact the servlet, you can always limit the number of requests and back them up with a [blocking queue through a threadpool executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#ThreadPoolExecutor%28int,%20int,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%20java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue%29).

Lastly, do not modify the servlet. You should be able to monitor it as a black box.